# delay in delivering websocket message used redis cloud as channel layer

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

currently, i am working on project that has one client side code written in python that send continuously screen shot of that system to server i.e my Django web-socket endpoint and my front end also connect to that web-socket and display that screen shot as live screen sharing.

In this i have used Redis cloud free version for testing. firstly i have used in-memory channel layer and it is working really fine. but it is not preferred in production , so i want to switch it to redid but it becomes slow. i mean front-end side web-socket connection receive messages with so much delay. can anyone explain what is getting wrong here and what can be the optimal way to solve this problem?